# bootstrap/JS/Ajax after button click get form TO CHANGE images

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I have a submit form with a click button, once the submit form its clicked, I want to change a series of images within my html site.

As of now I am using the following JS code but I am having trouble defining the appropriate success response.

```
<script type=text/javascript>                                                                     
$(function() {
$("#valueme").click(function() {                                                                  
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/mypythonscript/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                           
        data: { 
                input1: $('input[name="input1"]').val(),
                input2: $('input[name="input2"]').val(),
              },
        success: function(data) {
            //$ ('#photo_link1_div').text(data.photo_link1);                        
            //$ ('#photo_link2_div').text(data.photo_link2);                        
        }
    });                                                                                           
 });                                                                                              
 });
</script>
```

The data that mypythonscript returns is a dictionary with the links to all the images that I want to change in the html site, i.e., mypythonscript returns `{photolink1:'../static/img/myphoto1.jgp',photolink2:'../static/img/myphoto2.jgp'}`.

Using such data I'd like to change the background images in my html by changing the DIVs background image urls.  As of now the DIVs in my html look like (ideally I do not have to change this part but rather the JS part):

```
<div id="photo_link1_div" style="background-image: url(../static/img/anotherphotowanttochange.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 200px; height: 310px; background-size: 100% auto;" align="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the success function you're trying to update the text attribute from the links, try to change their background css as this example:

```
$ ('#photo_link1_div').css('background-image', data.photo_link1);                        
$ ('#photo_link2_div').css('background-image', data.photo_link2);
```

Comment: @Wallyson, it's great answer, just need to add url for my specific case as suggested by Alexey above... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. You need to change css property 'background-image' in success ajax callback. Try this it should help:

```
$('#photo_link1_div').css('background-image', 'url('+ data.photo_link1 +')');                        
$('#photo_link2_div').css('background-image', 'url('+ data.photo_link2 +')');
```

Good luck!